# Redis-Reative:Cache Update Fails

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, redis, project-reactor

Context:
We are building and api which calls another api and upon external api call successful save response into redis cache.

Spring_boot_version = '2.3.1.RELEASE'

**what works**

**Update Redis using Jedis**

```
  redisTemplate.opsForValue().set(cacheKey , cacheValue , Duration.ofSeconds(10s)).subscribe()
```

**Get Using reactive redis Template--Successful**

```
redisTemplate.opsForValue().get("cacheKey")
```

**What Fails**

**Update cache using reactive redisTemplate**

```
redisTemplate.opsForValue().set(cacheKey , cacheValue , Duration.ofSeconds(10s))
```

**Get Using reactive redis Template--Failed**

```
redisTemplate.opsForValue().get("cacheKey")
```

**Redis Configuration**

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnClass(
    ReactiveRedisTemplate::class,
    RedisConnectionFactory::class,
    LettuceConnectionFactory::class,
    ReactiveRedisConnectionFactory::class
)
open class RedisConfiguration
`{`

    @Bean
    open fun reactiveRedisConnectionFactory(): ReactiveRedisConnectionFactory {
        return LettuceConnectionFactory()
    }

    @Bean
    open fun reactiveRedisConnection(redisConnectionFactory: ReactiveRedisConnectionFactory): ReactiveRedisConnection
    {
        return redisConnectionFactory.reactiveConnection
    }

    @Bean
    open fun reactiveRedisTemplateString(connectionFactory: ReactiveRedisConnectionFactory?): ReactiveRedisTemplate<String,String> {
        return ReactiveRedisTemplate(
            connectionFactory,
            RedisSerializationContext.string()
        )
    }


}
```

Do i have to add any additional steps in order to update redis cache using redis reactive?And subscribe is right way to do? Any issues with it?